# Google script onchange trigger is firing twice

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, onchange

I am using google script onChange trigger by adding it manually. The sheet is fetching data from an external source and creating new rows as the data is received. So there are 2 events taking place.

1. A new row is added
2. Data is written on this new row.

The onChange() trigger is running twice for the same reason but I need to just run it once. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use the [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) to obtain information about the cause of the trigger firing

So, for `onChange` there is e.g. the event object `changeType` which can contain the values

- EDIT
- INSERT_ROW
- INSERT_COLUMN
- REMOVE_ROW
- REMOVE_COLUMN
- INSERT_GRID
- REMOVE_GRID
- FORMAT
- OTHER

This can help you to specify that your script shall run only if a certain type of `Change` takes place.

Sample:

```
function runMeOnIsertRow(e){
  if(e.changeType == 'INSERT_ROW'){
    //do something
  } else{
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just tried the above mentioned approach and at it gives me the exact result what I was looking for. Will keep testing for a couple of days and will get back if there is any issue or if I ll need some other help regarding the same. Thank you again :)